# What's wrong? $GL(V):= \{V\in \mathbb{C}^n : \exists W\in \mathbb{C}^n , VW = WV = 1\}$

Tags: symbols, math-operators, brackets, definition

I used `$GL(V)=: \{V\in \mathbb{C}^n : \exists W\in \mathbb{C}^n, VW = WV = 1\}$`,  which is to express

[image]

as highlighted.

But it sounds having errors, although it can compile. But I want to know is there anything that I can make it better.

Thank you!

Comment: For one thing, the spacing won’t be correct unless you put the entire expression in a single `$...$` or `\(...\)` block.

Comment: Hello, @Davislor, sounds better, thanks:-)

Comment: Welcome to the site!

Comment: It’s ambiguous in this sample whether `GL(V)` is the product of a variable *G* and a function *L*, or a function named GL. In the latter case, you might want to format it differently, e.g. `\DeclareMathOperator{\GL}{GL}` or `\newcommand{\GL}{\mathop{\textnormal{\slshape GL}}}`.

Comment: I'm not understanding what you mean by "sounds having errors" and "sounds better".

Comment: You should use simply `:` instead of `\colon` for a "colonesque" "such that". In math mode, the colon is a relation, hence inserts equal space on both sides of itself, as opposed to `\colon`, which puts much more space after it than before.

Answer (score 1):

I add my proposal using simply `\mathsf{GL}` (sans-serif font) for `GL`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}
\begin{document}
$\mathsf{GL}(\mathrm{V})\eqqcolon\{\mathrm{V}\in \mathbb{C}^n \colon \exists \mathrm{W}\in \mathbb{C}^n, \mathrm{VW} = \mathrm{WV} = 1\}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If you choose to render `V` in upright lettering toward the end of the formula, you should probably give it the same typographic treatment in `GL(V)`.

Comment: @Mico It is absolutely true :-) I provide to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

You wrote,

> I want to know is there anything that I can [do to] make it better

If the `GL` term is an operator, it's best to typeset it using upright roman letters. Separately, I think the overall look would improve if slightly greater visual prominence were given to the curly braces, e.g., by making them `\big`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb} % for '\mathbb' macro
\usepackage{amsmath} % for '\DeclareMathOperator' macro
\DeclareMathOperator{\GL}{GL}
\usepackage{mathtools} % for '\eqqcolon' macro
\begin{document}
\[
\GL(V) \eqqcolon \bigl\{ V\in \mathbb{C}^n : \exists W\in \mathbb{C}^n, VW = WV = 1 \bigr\}
\]
\end{document}
```